# Difference between vjp and jvp

Tags: calculus

What is the difference between Jacobian Vector Product (jvp), and Vector Jacobian Product (vjp), and why do we need both of these terms, why is only one of them not enough?

I found these two in PyTorch autograd,

```
torch.autograd.functional.vjp(func, inputs, v=None, create_graph=False, strict=False)
```

Function that computes the dot product between a vector v and the Jacobian of the given function at the point given by the inputs.

```
torch.autograd.functional.jvp(func, inputs, v=None, create_graph=False, strict=False)
```

Function that computes the dot product between the Jacobian of the given function at the point given by the inputs and a vector v.

Comment: Please could you provide a reference with the definition of both or give a bit of context? I found the JVP but not the VJP.

Comment: I updated it now

Answer (score 3):

Basing on what I understand:
Auto-gradient cannot compute the Jacobian directly(well, there are functions that compute Jacobian for sure but they are also implemented basing on JVP or VJP, mostly VJP), but it can compute Jacobian-Vector Product(JVP) or Vector-Jacobian Product(VJP). And we have both of them because they have their own advantage and disadvantage.

To be specific:
$m$: the function targets shape, normally is $1$ for a scaler loss.
$n$: the number of parameters that we need to compute the partial gradients for.
$\mathbf{J}$: a Jacobian matrix in shape of $m*n$.
$\vec{v}$: this is actually a bit different in JVP and VJP, so I put its detail in each case.

In JVP, it computes: $\mathbf{J}\vec{v}$(this, and the formula below are both vector-matrix multiplication, not dot product), where $\vec{v}$ is a vector in shape of $n*1$. So if v is $\vec{e}_i$(where every element is $0$ except the $i$-th element being $1$), we can compute the $i$-th column of Jacobian, which means after $n$ iterations, we get the Jacobian matrix itself. The advantage of JVP is, it can be computed along the forward process(so it is called the forward mode), so we do not need to store the intermediate values.

In VJP, it computes: $\vec{v}^T\mathbf{J}$, where $\vec{v}$ is a vector in shape of $m*1$. So if v is $\vec{e}_i$, we can compute the $i$-th row of Jacobian, which means after $m$ iterations, we get the Jacobian matrix itself. But since the computation of this chained matrix-vector product goes from back to front(thus it is also called the reverse mode), we need to store the intermediate values so we can compute the gradient in respect to them.

However, even the VJP requires us to use more memory, we probably still prefer to use VJP, since it requires $m$(most of time, $m=1$) iteration, while $n$ could be millions or billions.

Reference that might help, for why JVP and VJP's computational orders are different and more details:

1. https://nickmcgreivy.scholar.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf5041/files/ast558_seminar_tutorial_on_automatic_differentiation-2.pdf, this is more clear.
2. https://matt-graham.github.io/slides/ad/index.html page 9-16